# Asp.Net Wizard in ASPxCallBackPanel control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, callback, devexpress

Im using ASPxPopUpControll in which I have ASPxCallBack panel. THis CallbackPanel was embeded there because I wanted to have solution based on callbacks despite of reloading page each time.

In this CallBackPanel I've embeded asp:Wizard control.

What I want to achive is get rid of postbacks after clicking next previous etc buttons in this wizzard.

Any hints?

Maybe there is other way to create nice wizard without any postbacks ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxCallbackPanel cannot intercept postbacks and "convert" them to callbacks as the MS UpdatePanel does this.  So, a possible solution is to replace the ASPxCallbackPanel with the MS UpdatePanel and use the Wizard inside it.  One more solution is to use the ASPxPageControl, position all required controls in its Pages and manage them manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into ajax and jquery for asynchronous postbacks, that way you don't get a page refresh and you would only need to update a smaller part of the ui.